# i have problem with multiple form with the same id with google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Hi i have many **forms** inside `multiple pages` all of them the with the `same id` (**success message**) after submitted and `same class names` when i'm sending the form which ***e.g*** inside **home page** i put element selector through id with **Page PATH** with **match regex** something like that `\/(en|es)\/` it works good without problem ... but when i'm going to page `www.something.com/send-something/233?search=profile` the form submitted through old id which was for `home page` i tried to inject custom javascript something like :

```
function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('#sendReqSurgyForm1');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    if (els[i] === {{Page URL}}) {


        return i;
    
      
    }
  }
  return '(nothing sent)';
}
```

with adding matching **Page URL** with **match regex** something like that to `https:\/\/www\.something\.com\/(ar|en)\/send-something\/[0-9]+\?source=[a-zA-Z]+\_?[a-zA-Z]+`

to matching the **url:** `www.something.com/send-something/233?search=profile`

the trigger always works with **home page** but trigger which located in `www.something.com/send-something/233?search=profile`  not success and the result of javascript always returns `nothing sent` .. please help to fix this problem

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs. `id` at all times **must be unique** *per page*.

Comment: @connexo i'm using angular so i'm using the same component(form) in multiple pages .

Comment: As long as you make sure you never have more than one element with the same `id` value on a page, no problem.

Comment: i'm trying to fetch all forms with the same id arround the web pages then check if the `current url === {{Page URL}}` start execute the trigger which matches pattern inside `Page URL` ..  note : `Page URL` is a built in variable existed in gtm to match with regex or any other function .

Comment: Hi, is the angular component be configured or add a callback function.If yes maybe you can add datalayer snippet on it to get the form information.

Comment: @Darrellwan yes it's angular component .. i fixed this problem through setting for every form different `virtual id` through `setAttribute("id", "newid")` for every form then using `element visibility` and put `newid` for id selection in GTM .. thanks for trying to help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the Answer is SPA Angular using SPA so it can be multiple form with the same component so i solved this problem through setting id for every form with different urls
for example if you have multiple forms in angular inside multiple routing page  as i explained in the main topic question .. to fix this problem you can setting id for every form submissions through js by setting new `id` for every form submission by `setting Attribute` for id based different urls.

**main_id = exampleForm**

```
function(){

var ids = document.getElementById("exampleForm");//main id

var current_url = window.location.href;//current url of visitor

var dir_match = location.pathname+location.search;//the path of website after .com
var send_req = 'https://www.example.com/'+dir_match.match(/[ar][r]|[en]n/)+'/surgery-request/'+dir_match.match(/[0-9]+/)+'?source=profile';//link1 which have form1
var send_req2 = 'https://www.example.com/'+dir_match.match(/[ar][r]|[en]n/)+'/surgery-request/'+dir_match.match(/[0-9]+/)+'?source=profile2';//link2 which have form2
var home_url = 'https://www.example.com/'+dir_match.match(/[ar][r]|[en][n]/)+'/';//link3 which have form3
if(current_url == send_req){
    /* if current_url equal to link1 set new id e.g =  `forms_req_surgery` */
    last_send_req = ids.setAttribute("id", "forms_req_surgery");
    var elm = document.getElementById('forms_req_surgery');
    var last_var = elm.id;/* get the name of id */
    return last_var; // return the name of id after changed set 
}else if(current_url == home_url){
    last_home_url = ids.setAttribute("id", "home_req");
    var elm2 = document.getElementById('home_req');
    var last2_var =  elm2.id;
    return last2_var;
  }else if(current_url == send_req2){
    last_send_req2 = ids.setAttribute("id", "forms_req_surgery2");
    var elm3 = document.getElementById('forms_req_surgery2');
    var last3_var =  elm3.id;
    return last3_var;
  }

}
```